# Three.js: How to create new 'morphing' geometry if I have all necessary buffers?

Tags: javascript, three.js, arraybuffer

I'm using a web-worker to load a `.json` file of an animated 3D model. For each of the big arrays (vertices, normals, etc.), I'm transferring an `Float32Array` buffer back to the UI thread. Since such buffers are [transferable objects](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects), this will take (almost) *zero time*.

Now, it turns out that WebGL (and therefore, Three.js) use `Float32Array` buffers internally, too. This means I could probably load this 3D animation without copying anything, spending almost zero time in the main thread. Isn't that nice?

But it's not clear how to do that part: In the main thread, we have array buffers available for the vertices, normals (the main ones, and the 'morph' ones) and faces. How do I create a working `Geometry` (or `BufferGeometry`) from these, without translating or copying the data?

```
var scene,
    vertices, normals, faces,
    morphVertices, morphNormals; // <-- we have all these as typed arrays

var geometry = ...; // <-- insert code here

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ morphTargets: true });
var object3D = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(object3D);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605806/681588) gives a hint, but only point 7 seems relevant, it assumes there is already some `Geometry` instance, and it doesn't handle morph-targets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on the [mesh loading portion of THREE.GLTF2Loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ee87cc5c239c4286f558d5be1c0b30871bec78a2/examples/js/loaders/GLTF2Loader.js#L2082-L2253).

```
// Create BufferGeometry and assign vertices and normals.
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
geometry.setIndex( new THREE.BufferAttribute( faces, 3 ) );

// Create material.
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  morphTargets: true,
  morphNormals: true
});

// Set up morph target attributes.
var posAttr = new THREE.BufferAttribute( morphVertices, 3 );
var normAttr = new THREE.BufferAttribute( morphNormals, 3 );
for (var i = 0; i < posAttr.array.length; i++) {
  posAttr.array[i] += geometry.attributes.position.array[i];
}
for (var j = 0; j < normAttr.array.length; j++) {
  normAttr.array[j] += geometry.attributes.normal.array[j];
}

// Assign morph target attributes.
geometry.morphAttributes.position = [ posAttr ];
geometry.morphAttributes.normal = [ normAttr ];

// Create Mesh.
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.updateMorphTargets();

// Apply 50/50 blend of morph targets and default position/normals.
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 0.5;
```

three.js r86-dev.

Comment: I was trying to do something similar with THREE.Point. But unfortunately, the updateMorphTargets() is not available on THREE.Point. I guess Point is not really a mesh? I will post it as a separate question